# How install theme bought in themeforest in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I can't upload my custom theme. I want to upload a theme from the themeforest How to upload my custom theme?

Can anyone please tell me how to install the themeforest theme on react js and use it full demo

I'd like to install a jobboard theme form themeforest. Please I'm facing the problem installing

Comment: You really need to edit your question with specific details. Currently you've provided nothing but a question about a theme. And then you repeated yourself a few times (presumably to bypass the minimum-question-size rule). And then you even posted an answer, asking again how to install your theme. There is just no way to answer this question, as written.

Comment: I suggest reading the help section, specifically about [on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as well as [tips for asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).